# Retrieve data from JSON using JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am attempting to get a value for a game from JSON, but there are multiple fields with the same name, so I was wondering whether there was a way in which I could just retrieve that individual value, here is the basic JSON structure:

```
"response": {

    "game_count": 119,
    "games": [
        {
            "appid": 3920,
            "playtime_forever": 0
        },
        {
            "appid": 4000,
            "playtime_forever": 278
        },
```

...

I need to somehow get a property by using an appID and then retrieving the `playtime_forever` key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your JSON to class and then query:

```
class ResponseJSON
{
    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public Result Response { get; set; }
}

class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("game_count")]
    public string Count { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("games")]
    public List<Game> Gmaes { get; set; }    
}

class Game 
{
    [JsonProperty("appid")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("playtime_forever")]
    public string PlayTime { get; set; }
}

var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseJSON>(jsonstr);
```

And then you can iterate through your object with a for loop:

```
foreach(game in resp.Respone.Games) {
   var playtime = game.PlayTime;
  // do stuff here
}
```

Or you can use linq to query your games:

```
var selectiveGames = resp.Response.Games.Where(x=> x.PlayTime == 220).ToList();
```

You need to add newtonsoft dll from [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to your project if you don't have it;

UPDATE: With original JSON the code above is working perfect.

Comment: I've done that and it just says ``Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`` on the foreach loop

Comment: Check the update @John I just tested your JSON with my console app and it's working

Comment: Nearly there, I'm just getting an error on ``response.Response.Games.Where`` : ``CommandRegistry.Result does not contain a definition for Games``

Comment: Any idea @Yasser ?

Comment: ? @Yasser there is no point in answering and just leaving the code not working

Comment: Hey @John I created a console app and the code above is working like a charm, the purpose here is to point you to the right direction if you couldn't get it done I would suggest you upload your code to github and we will take it from there